# Solutions $\lambda$ of $\displaystyle 1-\lambda \mathcal{F}(e^{-ix})(\xi)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, real-numbers, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am looking for reals $\lambda$ such that
$$1-\lambda \mathcal{F}(e^{-ix})(\xi)=0,$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform. Using the Dirac distribution $\delta$, I found that the Fourier transform of $e^{-ix}$ is $\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(-1-\xi)$. So the equation becomes:
$$1-\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda \delta(-1-\xi)=0.$$
Please help me to solve this equation. I thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you believe that this has any solution?  Are you sure that thie left hand side is not an operator?

Comment: Honnestly, I really dont know. I solved an integral equation and the condition for existence of a unique solution is this condition not equal to 0.